# Can a connected second countable manifold have cardinality $>2^{\aleph_0}$?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

> Can a connected second countable manifold have cardinality $>2^{\aleph_0}$?

From [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67962/cardinality-of-connected-manifolds), a connected Hausdorff manifold must have cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. How about if we change the condition "Hausdorff" to "second countable"?

Comment: If you're talking about manifolds of finite dimension, every coordinate patch has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ (or smaller if the dimension is $0$). There is a countable basis of coordinate patches. If you're talking about Banach (or Fréchet) manifolds, the assertion is false because there are Banach (Fréchet) spaces of larger cardinality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of connectedness: since the manifold $M$ is second-countable, it has a countable atlas (every open covering of a second-countable space admits a countable subcovering). Therefore, it is countable union of subsets homeomorphic to the unit ball of $\Bbb R^n$, whose cardinality is at most $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Therefore its cardinality is $\le \aleph_0\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$.